# /users/{id} and /users/{id}/timeline - filter parameter?

Tags: support, status-completed, documentation

Both /users/{id} and /users/{id}/timeline say they take a filter parameter for users' names, but it seems to do nothing. Are they not supposed to be there?

Comment: Its not there anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed. Looks like a bug.

Example:

- Username: Joel Potter
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/65611?filter=blahblah